# Trouble with binascii.Error: Odd-length string

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.x, rsa

I am attempting to write an program that encrypts and decrypts text files using RSA. I seem to have run into an issue while using unhexlify from binascii.

```
out_format = '%%0%dx' % (chunk_size * 2,)
plain = pow(coded, int(key), int(private_modulus))

chunk = unhexlify((out_format % plain).encode())
```

When my program gets to that last line, it throws an error "binascii.Error: Odd-length string"

Comment: chunk_size = int(log(float(public_modulus), 256))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `plain` value is *larger* than will fit in `chunk_size * 2` hex digits, so the resulting string contains an odd number of hex digits here. You'd need to handle that overflow.

Example with just 2 hex digits and the value 256 (hex 100):

```
>>> '%02x' % 256
'100'
>>> unhexlify('%02x' % 256)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
binascii.Error: Odd-length string
```

I am not familiar with how RSA decryption works, so I cannot say if the problem is with the calculation of `plain` or that you should mask the value to fit the chunk size. To fit the chunk size, you could mask the `plain` value with:

```
mask = (1 << (chunksize * 8)) - 1
plain &= mask
```

I'd use `str.format()` here instead of old-style string formatting with `%`; you can incorporate the width more easily:

```
unhexlify('{1:0{0}x}'.format(chunk_size * 2, plain))
```

Encoding to bytes is optional, `binascii.unhexlify` accepts strings too, at least on Python 3.3.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The tip on .format just saved me a headache and a half. I'm still not sure about the plain value. I am leaning towards masking the value.